# Connecting to a smb share on a Mac on a network with a static ip

Tags: networking, macos, samba, smb, static-ip

My client has a router that uses a static IP address and has 2 Macs attached to it, one running MacOS 10.13.x and is used as a Filemaker server, and the other running Ventura and is used as a file server. I've opened the 5003 port for Filemaker and it works well. I also opened 445 and 139 for the file server smb shares and remotely it doesn't work at all from the Starlink network they use remotely, using smb://161.xxx.xxx.xxx:445 or 139. They have a different network that uses dynamic DNS with a file server (MacOS 10.13) attached that uses afp, instead of smb and it works well too, but the smb share just doesn't want to cooperate. This is not my forte, so I feel a bit out of my depth but I'm comfortable in Terminal if that is what it will take to get this to work.

Comment: Maybe the Internet service provider blocks port 445. Are you happy with the risks of opening ports like 445 and monitoring for intrusion?